# Arrow styles for upper limits and error bars

Tags: python, matplotlib, errorbar

How do I change the arrow style when making upper limits or error bars?
I want to plot a data set of upper limits and have the arrows not filled.

My code so far looks like this:

```
testdata = np.random.random(300)
plt.errorbar(np.arange(300), testdata, xerr=None, yerr=0.04, uplims=True, fmt='_', capsize=3)
```

And returns this plot:

[image]

How can I get the following kind of arrows?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using a combination of `elinewidth` and `set_fillstyle`

```
testdata = np.random.random(300)
fig, axs = plt.subplots()
plot, caps, bars = plt.errorbar(np.arange(300), testdata, xerr=None, yerr=0.04, uplims=True, fmt='_', capsize=2, elinewidth=0.5)
caps[0].set_fillstyle('none')
```